# jQuery - the autocomplete properties not getting applied to dynamically created combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the code in which the autocomplete works fine with the first combobox. if i just copy paste the combobox it is working but when the second combobox is created dynamically on button click the autocomplete is not working ?

**current code :**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
 height:17px;
 background:transparent;
 border-radius:0px;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
 width:150px;height:17px;
 background:transparent;
 border-radius:0px;
  }
  .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0em 0px 0em;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 0;
 background:transparent;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  function sendvalues()
  {
  alert();
  }
  function combo()
 {
 alert();
  $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
 }
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
   
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
  sendvalues();
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( ".combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
function loada()
{
document.getElementById("two").innerHTML=document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
}
</script>
<div id="one">


  <select class="combobox" id="one" onchange="sendvalues()" onload="combo()">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="kkk">kkk</option>
    <option value="sd">asf</option>
 <option value="abdfac">abasdfsac</option>
    <option value="kgfjkgkk">kkyk</option>
    <option value="sghkd">asgyjf</option>
 <option value="abyuic">abftfjvhjc</option>
    <option value="kkkgyjhk">kkgjk</option>
    <option value="sml,hud">asnjmf</option>
    
  </select>
   </div>
<br><br><br><br>

<button onclick="loada()" >click</button>
 <div id="two" onload="">
 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain points which I observed in your code which are little bit not correct to do with html. Chances are there you would have written in hurry so please ignore the points

1. Div Id is 'one' and in side selector also having id as one make sure ids are unique.

   2. your loada() function is just doing a copy paste job auto complete binding is missing .

So here I have changed your loada() function replace then it will work.

```
var counter = 0;
 function loada() {
     //         document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
     $("#one").clone().find('select').addClass('newControl' + counter).appendTo("#two");
     $('.newControl' + counter).combobox();
     counter++;
 }
```